# FCM send msg through firewall using firebase-admin library

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

In company we have firewall.
We've enabled `fcm.googleapis.com` 433 adress. But it havent helped. Still jboss application can not send push request using `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin` library.
I know about range of IPs but that is not possible for admins to maintain such range of IPs in our company.
But we can set it for url names (I was told so). But this one addres havent helped. I've looked into

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-admin    
com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http
```

And found few other addresses:

> https://accounts.google.com
>   https://iid.googleapis.com

Have anyone else opened firewall for such adresses? Maybe I need something else? (Ive sent it to network ppl, but they wont do it immediately, so maybe I can correct it before they start)

Comment: Ok, I can confirm. After I blocked accounts.google.com and iid.googleapis.com at home (no proxy, so no problem with testing) I was unable to send push with firebase-admin library. 
Problem was with idd.googleapis.com it was moving IP behind it very fast. Still with those host names I am sure I need them enabled.
Now I wonder if there are more host names needed for that library. Is there any author of this library? Cant find it in docs, except "big ip list" or "enable all" answers, and those cant be accepted solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that moment it worked for those 3 addresses. It is working for few days now. Forgot to mention it here. Will try post anything if it's gonna change. I am not sure when 3rd address is used, second one is during initialization of firebase mechanisms to take token.
For sure there is no need to make exception in firewall for specific database url that is given by your project, it is sent in parameters to fcm.googleapis.com and probably google use it somehow there. Would be nice for official answer here from one of fcm developers, but cant help it. Cheers

- https://fcm.googleapis.com
- https://accounts.google.com
- https://iid.googleapis.com